# by September or in September?

Tags: differences, prepositions

I'm preparing for my English grammar exam, and I faced this question

> The weather is going to be hot ........ September
>
> a. on
> b. at
> c. in
> d. by

I'm not sure whether the answer is *c* or *d*

Comment: 'c' is the most idiomatic, but 'd' cannot be judged wrong. Another poor exam question.

Answer (score 3):

A on September - wrong and meaningless. Although the usage "on a day in September" is accepted. "We went to the seaside on a day in September".

B at September - wrong and meaningless.

C in September = during the month of September

D by September = before and up to the time that the month of September starts

Which means that either C and D may be correct, depending on what is meant. This is a poor question if only one correct answer is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Both C and D are correct, you need better context to choose only one answer, otherwise it should accept two right answers.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please bear in mind that it's not good form to add answers which merely repeat what other answers have already said.

Comment: And please add an explanation as to why you think those are the right answers.